# Migrating from Visual studio 2008 to 2015

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, migration

I have code for a software written in C++ with MFC in Visual Studio 2005. Now I need to migrate it to Visual Studio 2015. How can I do it and what are the challenges to be countered?

Comment: Just open the 2005 solution in 2015 and see what happens. If you are lucky you don't need to do any thing more.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in comments, open your solution, it will be converted. The issues I had when doing so:

- Only blocking issue for compilation I had was to change the Unicode handling option in project options because one of the related options disapeared/changed its values. There is a report after the conversion is complete, read it!
- All possible issues with such a huge gap in compilator versions are still possible then. So be carefull of the warnings (activate them if not done)
- Running some code analysis may be a good idea to detect deprecated syntax/methods, I had some unexpected behaviour on old Microsoft methods that were a bit too permissive before (clearly it was my fault but for some reason the old compilator was kind with some of my mistakes).